# SwingWorker, publishing from within a large method call

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, swingworker

I have a swingworker which I would like to use to call a large and complicated method from another object, from within the doInBackground() swingworker method.

It looks like this:

```
public class HostGameTask extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        try {
            SwingGUI.poker.StartGame(true,(SwingGUI.numberOfSlots.getSelectedIndex()+1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> messages) {
        String latestMessage = messages.get(messages.size()-1);
    }
}
```

The StartGame method has a while loop inside it which waits for players to join. The poker object an object within SwingGUI, which has HostGameTask as a nested class.

Can I publish from within the StartGame() function?

Comment: What do you mean by "publish"?

Comment: a beware: given the name SwingGUI, it's easy to assume that it's somehow related to your ui, that is you might be accessing ui properties from within doInBackground - which would be **wrong**

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

No you can't given the way you've written your code?

Yes you can, if you pass a reference of the `SwingWorker` to the `StartGame` method.

Personally, I'd write an interface through which your `StartGame` method could communicate with the worker. Ths decouples your code and removes the reliance on the `SwingWorker` (because your `StartGame` method should not care about whose consuming its content, just how it goes about sending that information to interested parties).